# How to add React infinite scrolling to a table in ruby on rails

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

We are adding infinite scrolling to a table in an old project based on ruby on rails. We tried the library [react-infinite](https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite) but it did not work.

We installed it through bower

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.7",
    "jquery": "~1.9.1",
    "react": "~0.13.3",
    "react-simpletabs": "^0.7.0",
    "react-bootstrap-treeview": "0.1.0",
    "sisyphus": "1.1.3",
    "prototypejs": "1.7.1",
    "highcharts": "4.2.7",
    "js-grid": "1.5.3",
    "jquery-colorbox": "1.5.10",
    "react-infinite": "*"
  }
```

In application.js, we import it using

`//= require react-infinite`

Then we use it like this:

```
    <react-infinite containerHeight={200} elementHeight={40}>
  <ContentTable
    data={this.state.tableData}
    filterText={this.state.filterText}
    onUserClick={this.handleUserClick}
    dataType={this.props.dataType}
    showPublic={this.state.publicCheckbox}
  />
    </react-infinite>
```

But it did not make any difference. ContentTable is a customized table. And in the console, there is an error:
[image]

How can I make it work on a table? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller instead. I found it much better than the `react-infinite`.

Comment: is there a special reason why you are using bower? I rails took the right step forward with the webpacker gem's integration into the core of rails

Comment: @KonradD react-infinite-scroller is in ES6 but the old project is in ES5. I tried but the library could not be imported correctly using  `import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller'`. In the console, there's an error "SyntaxError: modules are not implemented yet" correspond to the import statement. This library may not work for this project.

Comment: Other js libraries were imported using bower. So I use it.